# Listbox: add a combobox as Item?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to make every item of a listbox as a combobox?
I need this because i made the listbox as checkable and then I need to make the user to choose from different options for every element of the list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not planning on distributing your application then you can also look at the TreeView Control. See this example.

**CODE**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With TreeView1.Nodes
        .Add , , "R1", "Root 1"
        .Add "R1", tvwChild, , "Test 1"
        .Add "R1", tvwChild, , "Test 2"
        .Add "R1", tvwChild, , "Test 3"
        .Add "R1", tvwChild, , "Test 4"
        .Add "R1", tvwChild, , "Test 5"

        .Add , , "R2", "Root 2"
        .Add "R2", tvwChild, , "Test 11"
        .Add "R2", tvwChild, , "Test 22"
        .Add "R2", tvwChild, , "Test 33"
        .Add "R2", tvwChild, , "Test 44"
        .Add "R2", tvwChild, , "Test 55"
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**USING THE CONTROL**

To be able to use the Treeview Control, your system must have `MSCOMCTL.OCX` registered. You can then add the control by Right Clicking on the

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**DESIGN TIME SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**DOWNLOAD THE OCX**

If you do not have the OCX then you can download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10019)

Comment: +1 You're answers have always amazed me. You fully describe each and every step that should be followed, and that too with pictures :)

Comment: Thank You Kartik :) That is because the answer is not only aimed at the `Asker` but anyone who comes here looking for a similar query ;)

Comment: The common controls library is not available for 64x installations (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-microsoft-office-HA010369476.aspx#_Toc254341418)

Comment: @remou: It is not available for office 64 bit but is available for office 32 bit on 64 bit windows

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve such an effect by replacing you listbox by a subform in datasheet view.
You will have the mimic the multiselect by providing a checkbox, and you could have a second column as a listbox.

Comment: Seems like the sensible solution to me. I general prefer continuous forms to datasheets, because it gives a better level of control, but *chacun à son goût* :)

Comment: @Remou: Having a form in Datasheet view gives you mostly the same level of control as the form in Form view: events, combo...just  a bit less cosmetic choice. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Headers and footers, for one, are a lot more than cosmetic. Also, at what point does layout switch from cosmetic to an important part of data entry? Which is the last control on a datasheet?